# Is there an object unique identifier in Python

Tags: python

This would be similar to the `java.lang.Object.hashcode()` method.

I need to store objects I have no control over in a set, and make sure that only if two objects are actually the same object (not contain the same values) will the values be overwritten.

Comment: Note that `hashCode()` in Java is not necessarily unique, it just has some carefully chosen semantics in conjunction with `equals()`.

Comment: And as posted below the Python's `hash()` has **exactly** the same semantics as `java.lang.Object.hashcode()`.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

```
id(x)
```

will do the trick for you. But I'm curious, what's wrong about the set of objects (which does combine objects by value)?

For your particular problem I would probably keep the set of ids or of wrapper objects. A wrapper object will contain one reference and compare by `x==y` <==> `x.ref is y.ref`.

It's also worth noting that Python objects have a `hash` function as well. This function is necessary to put an object into a set or dictionary. It is supposed to sometimes collide for different objects, though good implementations of `hash` try to make it less likely.

Comment: Down-voting one, because id(x) doesn't make sure of uniqueness for each object. The OP was very clear that he/she want to treat different objects containing the same value to be *different*.

Comment: @Roy on the contrary the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) say that `id(x)` _is_ "guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime" which would result in different objects with the same value having different id's (as long as they both exist at the same time) which would enable the OP to do what they wanted.

Comment: @sparrowt I see. I agree w/ you. The key point is that "the ID be unique *when two object with the same value co-exist*". `id()` seems to return the same ID for repeatedly created (and destroyed) objects with the same value, hence my original comment, but actually that's fine here, because OP stated that the IDs have to be unique when the objects coexist. Removing my down-vote.

Comment: Ah, cannot change my vote now, too late. Sorry for the confusion and the incorrect voting (honest mistake).

Comment: Unique IDs can also be useful for workflow management, to track inputs and outputs of tasks.

Comment: What is `x.ref` or `y.ref`? There is no `ref` attribute in Python.

Comment: @flow2k `x.ref` in this case would be the name of the property in the wrapper containing a reference to the original `x`, after assigning the wrapper to the variable `x`.

Answer (score 37):

That's what "`is`" is for.

Instead of testing "`if a == b`", which tests for the same value,

test "`if a is b`", which will test for the same identifier.

Comment: Would it be accurate to say that Python's "is" is like Java's "==" and Python's "==" is like Java's "equals()"?

Comment: For those wondering the answer to @Tyler question, the answer is yes. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/133024/885922

Answer (score 2):

As ilya n mentions, id(x) produces a unique identifier for an object.

But your question is confusing, since Java's hashCode method doesn't give a unique identifier.  Java's hashCode works like most hash functions: it always returns the same value for the same object, two objects that are equal always get equal codes, and unequal hash values imply unequal hash codes.  In particular, two different and unequal objects can get the same value.

This is confusing because cryptographic hash functions are quite different from this, and more like (though not exactly) the "unique id" that you asked for.

The Python equivalent of Java's hashCode method is hash(x).

Comment: That's why I explicitly mentioned java.lang.Object's hashcode method.  Which, by default, produces a unique long for that object.  I realize the other implementations of hashcode can, and do, differ.

Comment: But that's the point: hashCode doesn't produce a unique long.  It produces longs which try hard not to collide, but you can't map strings to longs and produce a unique value.

Comment: ...and old thread I know.  But I did want to point out that id() is unique only while both objects still exists.  Once freed, the id may be assigned to another object per "Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value."  [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id)

Comment: But in Python `hash(.)` doesn't work for lists... I know list is mutable but I just need to generate a number based on the contents of the list. Perhaps sum(myList), as a poor hash function...

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to compare objects before placing them in a set. set() semantics already takes care of this.

```
   class A(object): 
     a = 10 
     b = 20 
     def __hash__(self): 
        return hash((self.a, self.b)) 

   a1 = A()
   a2 = A()
   a3 = A()
   a4 = a1
   s = set([a1,a2,a3,a4])
   s
=> set([<__main__.A object at 0x222a8c>, <__main__.A object at 0x220684>, <__main__.A object at 0x22045c>])
```

Note: You really don't have to override **hash**  to prove this behaviour :-)

Comment: Your solution depends on the kind of class that is inherited from:
`class B(str): pass` if called with `set([B(), B()])` leads to `set([''])`. Identification from dictionaries usually implicitly depends on `id(x)` for objects, you should just use it explicitly and avoid corner cases.

Comment: @ArneRecknagel you are right. but what would you put in a set after checking id(x)?